# EC2 not sending logs to Cloudwatch

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My Linux EC2 server used as a reverse proxy isn't sending logs to cloudwatch log groups. 
The EC2 server is created using rhel-cattle AMI. And the configurations are done using ansible playbook. 
I have checked the awslogs.logs file. There were only INFO. No errors. What could be issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now.
The awslogs.conf had a state file configured whose path wasn't available.
Had to create the folder.